# Always showing environment as production while deploying using capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, puma

When I run the command **cap staging deploy**, then also it's producing the result as

```
puma:start
using conf file /var/www/rails/shared/tmp/puma.rb
01 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec puma -C /var/www/rails/shared/tmp/puma.rb --daemon
01 Puma starting in single mode...
01 * Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.5.0-p0), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
01 * Min threads: 0, max threads: 8
01 * Environment: production
01 * Daemonizing..
```

In **deploy.rb** file it has the following line

```
set :puma_env, fetch(:rack_env, fetch(:rails_env, 'production'))
```

If I change its value from production to any other value, then it is reflected there as well. 
Does this line has any effect in setting the deploy environment?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/configuration/), the second parameter of `fetch` will act as a default value for the first parameter if it has not been set yet.

As a result, if your `deploy.rb` file did not declare `rails_env` value then the value will become `production` as it is the default value.

You can override this behaviour by adding this line to your `deploy.rb`

`set :rails_env, 'your_environment_here'`

Comment: I have fixed the issue by adding the line **environment 'production'** in the /var/www/rails/shared/puma.rb file